# Merge Dataset Based on NULL Values of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets in this form...

```
       First Dataset

Unique_id   Name    Website      Avg                  
2323aa777  Medigen  medigen.org  32                            
NaN        Aster    astera.gm    31                
4373cc987  Smenda   Nan          32                


  Second Dataset

Unique_id    Website      Rev
3232hh322    smenda.gm    433433
54542ff23    dretbey.gm   542322
8367ff233    brtetu.gm    343433
```

I have to consolidate both the dataset in such a way that wherever Unique_id is available in dataset_1 , use that as a key to merge both.. otherwise use Website column for merging..

I have used this logic, but it's not working..

```
df_merged = np.where(df_1['Unique_id'].isnull(),df_1.merge(df_2,how='left',on='website',df_1.merge(df_2,how='left',on='unique_id')
```

Can someone suggest the correct way

Comment: You have multiple `Unique_id` and `Website` columns in your sample data...

Comment: They are 2 different datasets

Comment: @Patrik, can you give signficant examples and show the exact matching expected outupt ? Because, as you can see, there is no matches between your actual datasets.

Comment: It might be more readable to create a separate column in each dataset that contains the merge key: `df1['merge_key'] = df1['Unique_id']; df1['merge_key'] = df1.merge_key.fillna(df1.Website)` Same for the other df. Then merge on the new temporary column. That might be more obvious what you're doing for maintainability in the future and easier to debug when it goes wrong.

Comment: @Timeless The final O/P dataset will contains 5 columns ie. Unique_id , Name, Website, Avg and Revenue.... We have to merge datasets based on Unique_Id... Incase it is not available, then we have to use website

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your desired result is to mask `df_1` according to whether `Unique_id` is `NaN`, and then merge that part with `df_2` on `Unique_id`, and merge the other part with `df_2` on `Website`. I've modified your `df_2` data to make sure there are some matches:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Unique_id': {0: '2323aa777', 1: np.nan, 2: '4373cc987'},
    'Name': {0: 'Medigen', 1: 'Aster', 2: 'Smenda'},
    'Website': {0: 'medigen.org', 1: 'astera.gm', 2: 'Nan'},
    'Avg': {0: 32, 1: 31, 2: 32}
})
#    Unique_id     Name      Website  Avg
# 0  2323aa777  Medigen  medigen.org   32
# 1        NaN    Aster    astera.gm   31
# 2  4373cc987   Smenda          Nan   32

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Unique_id': {0: '3232hh322', 1: '2323aa777', 2: '8367ff233'},
    'Website': {0: 'smenda.gm', 1: 'dretbey.gm', 2: 'astera.gm'},
    'Rev': {0: 433433, 1: 542322, 2: 343433}
})
#    Unique_id     Website     Rev
# 0  3232hh322   smenda.gm  433433
# 1  2323aa777  dretbey.gm  542322
# 2  8367ff233   astera.gm  343433

mask = df_1['Unique_id'].isna()
merged_id = df_1[~mask].merge(df_2, how='inner', on='Unique_id', suffixes=['', '_2']).drop('Website_2', axis=1)
merged_ws = df_1[mask].merge(df_2, how='inner', on='Website', suffixes=['', '_2']).drop('Unique_id_2',axis=1)
res = pd.concat([merged_id, merged_ws]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Unique_id     Name      Website  Avg     Rev
0  2323aa777  Medigen  medigen.org   32  542322
1        NaN    Aster    astera.gm   31  343433
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
out = (pd.concat([df_1.merge(df_2, on=key, suffixes=("", "_"))
                  for key in ["Unique_id", "Website"]])
            [list(df_1.columns) + ["Rev"]] #optional
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out) #based on @Nick's reproducible examples

   Unique_id     Name      Website  Avg     Rev
0  2323aa777  Medigen  medigen.org   32  542322
0        NaN    Aster    astera.gm   31  343433
```